# How to combine multiple queries in paginate

Tags: cakephp, pagination, multiple-select

in my app i want to integrate a distance search by zipcode.

```
$result['zipcode'] = $this->Locations->find('all', array('conditions' => array('plz' => $param)));
if (count($city['Plz']) > 1)
    $result['city'] = $this->Locations->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ort' => $city['Stadt']['name'], 'plz !=' => $city['Plz']['zipcode'])));
    $this->Locations->virtualFields['distance'] = 'ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(Locations.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS('.$city["Stadt"]["lat"].')) + COS(RADIANS(Locations.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('.$city["Stadt"]["lat"].')) * COS(RADIANS(Locations.lng) - RADIANS('.$city["Stadt"]["lng"].')) ) * 6380';
    $result['near'] = $this->Locations->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'plz !=' => $param,
            'ort !=' => $city['Stadt']['name'],
        ),
        'order' => 'distance ASC'
    ));
```

i want to display results in order by zipcode, city (if city has many zipcodes) and near, so i did it this way.
but now i want to paginate this results by cake pagination.
is it possible to make these queries getting one i.e.

```
$this->Locations->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'order' => 'RESULTS BY ZIPCODE, RESULTS BY CITY, RESULTS BY MISSMATCH ORDERED BY DISTANCE'
)));
```

how would you solve this problem?

M.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP you can specify multiple fields to sort on via an associative array;

```
$this->MyModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(/* .... */),
    'order' => array(
        'MyModel.field1' => 'asc',
        'MyModel.field2' => 'desc',
        'MyModel.field3' => 'asc',
    )
);
```

Comment: i know, but there are 3 kinds of request which i want to combine to one, so i get first all results where zipcode matches, next where city matches and last all others where city and zipcode not matches in order by distance.

Comment: Hm, why not perform those searches in a single query, but in stead of 'filtering', 'rank' the results?

Comment: i dont want to manualy set joins because this model has associations and im at beginning to create my app. i dont know if i add or del some associations. is there a way to get the full query string from model in beforeFind and exit without action?